# Writing linear functional as a sum of 2 linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Suppose that $q_1, q_2$ are semi-norms on a real or complex vector space $V$, $\rho$ is a linear functional on V, and $|\rho(x)|\leq q_1+q_2$. Show that $\rho$ can be expressed as $\rho_1+\rho_2$ which are both linear functionals on $V$ and, $|\rho_i|\leq q_i$ for each i.

There was a hint in the textbook to define the semi-norm $p(x,y)=q_1(x)+q_2(y)$ and the linear functional $\sigma_0(x,x)=\rho(x)$.

I then extended (using one of the Hahn-Banach extension theorems) $\sigma_0(x,x)$ to $\sigma(x,y)=\rho_1(x)+\rho_2(y)$. Along with this theorem, we get that $|\sigma(x,y)|\leq p(x,y)$. This equals $\rho(x)$ on the diagonal subspace. I'm not very familiar with functional analysis. Is this the right approach so far? Also, how do we verify that $|\rho_i|\leq q_i$ for each i?

Comment: This the right approach, as $\rho(x)=\sigma(x,x)=\rho_1(x)+\rho_2(x).$ Moreover $|\rho_1(x)|=|\sigma(x,0)|\le p(x,0)=q_1(x)$ and  $|\rho_2(x)|=|\sigma(0,x)|\le p(0,x)= q_2(x)$